# Localization and space of morphisms

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

I have a question regarding the proof of Proposition 2.19 of [Factorization homology of topological manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5522) by Ayala and Francis. In the final paragraph of the proof (more specifically, in the second sentence of the paragraph), they seem to make use of the following assertion:

> ($\ast$) Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category and $\mathcal{W}\subset \mathcal{C}$ its subcategory. The localization map $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ induces a weak homotopy equivalence
> $$\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,\mathcal{C})\times_{\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}}(\mathcal{W}\times \mathcal{W})\to\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}]^{-1})\times _{\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]\times \mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]} (\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]^{\simeq}\times \mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]^{\simeq}).$$

(If it's releveant at all, I should mention that they seem to be using assertion ($\ast$) only when $\mathcal{C}$ is the nerve of an ordinary category.)
Here by *localization*, we mean that for each $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$, the functor $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}],\mathcal{D})\to\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ is fully faithful and its essential image consists of the functors which maps every morphism in $\mathcal{W}$ to an equivalence of $\mathcal{D}$. Also, the superscript "$\simeq$" indicates maximal sub Kan complex.

Does anyone know how to prove ($\ast$)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In words, I think the claim is "the ∞-groupoid completion of the category of commutative squares in $\mathcal{C}$ where the (wlog) horizontal arrows are in $\mathcal{W}$ is (weakly homotopy) equivalent to the ∞-groupoid completion of the category of commutative squares in $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ where the horizontal arrows are equivalences". This sounds like a highly non-trivial claim to me! Already for the case $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{W}$ this is saying that $\textrm{Fun} (\Delta^1, -)$ preserves the weak homotopy equivalence $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} [\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: How exactly do commutative squares emerge here?  The left side looks like zigzags of length 3, with two outer arrows being weak equivalences.  It is not clear to me why such a zigzag should complete to a commutative square.

Comment: The objects of $\textrm{Fun} (\Delta^1, \mathcal{C})$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ and the morphisms are commutative squares. I presume the pullbacks here are strict rather than homotopy, but I think it makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @Ken In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is a ordinary category the simplicial set $\textrm{Fun} (\Delta^1, \mathcal{C}) \times_{\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}} (\mathcal{W} \times \mathcal{W})$ (strict pullback) is isomorphic to the first level of the Rezk classification diagram of $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W})$. So this would appear to be a part of the generally accepted result that the Rezk classification diagram of $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W})$ is levelwise weakly homotopy equivalent to the Rezk classification diagram of $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$. I can't find a reference for this, though.

Comment: Ah, no, that can't be true in complete generality since it would imply $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ has a certain factorisation property. Hmmm. But it is true when $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W})$ is nice enough.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you be more specific about how nice $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W})$ should be?

Comment: Well, I have [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8192) with Aaron Mazel-Gee about it...

Comment: Thank you for your reference. I am not sure if the result of the paper fits into the problem I have in mind, but it will definitely give some insight. I will take a look at it.